How auto generate a class with observable fields from another class
Let's say you have a class like this:
public class InitialData
{
    public int InitialDataID { get; set; }
    public string InitialDataName { get; set; }
    public string InitialDataDescription { get; set; }
}

I want to create another class named InitialDataView:
public partial class InitialDataView : ObservableObject
{
    // For each InitialData property, create an ObservableProperty
    [ObservableProperty]
    int _InitialDataID;
    [ObservableProperty]
    string _InitialDataName;
    [ObservableProperty]
    string _InitialDataDescription;
}

In a way that for every field I add (ex int newField) in InitialData, the InitialDataView is auto updated and the corresponding field is added (ex [ObservableProperty] int newField;).
I can add them one by one, but I want to find a better way.

You can use a package like Fody to auto-generate observables, and regular c# inheritance to compose the classes

Do you want to add the ObservableProperty at runtime?

Does it  help How to dynamically generate C# class at compile time??
